# iPhone App Running Slower on Simulator

Tags: ios, memory, ios4, ios-simulator

I am currently working on an iPhone app where I use **2 main timers** that make the game work as one piece. The only problem I've encountered so far is that **when I run it on the iOS Simulator from Xcode the game seems to lag a bit, and all of the animations run slower**. I'm not sure if this is a memory issue, but isn't the iOS Simulator supposed to run just as smooth as the iPhone? When I run it on my iPod Touch 4th Generation, I don't encounter this problem. Is there a way I can fix this, or does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I regularly encounter graphics performance issues on simulator.  Not sure there is an answer.

Comment: What's the host machine for the simulator? I wouldn't be surprised to see speed differences.

Comment: What do you mean by host machine?

Comment: My experience is that the simulator is faster running on a macbook with 2.4Ghz. Anyway, you should consider to design your game in a way that is not so sensitive to computer speed - who knows what happens if real mutitasking is being introduced...

Comment: It's running on a 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo with 4GB of Memory RAM. So I don't think that's the issue. I think it's somewhat related to the iOS Simulator, is there a way I can like change the memory being used by the simulator?

Comment: you might want to run instruments both on simulator and device and compare memory, resources, speed etc. I don't know your memory requirements but I doubt that's an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frameworks are designed to work with specific hardware on device for graphics acceleration.  This is not present in the simulator, so you'll see diminished performance on graphics-intensive applications.  You might however see increased performance in the simulator in non-graphics related areas.  The bottom line is always test on real hardware - the simulator is just a convenience.

Comment: This is especially true if you're using OpenGL. The simulator will end up simulating a lot of the OpenGL stuff in software, and it doesn't even support the same set of extensions as hardware.